# Is it possible to upload a new beta APK to Google Play and remove the existing production APK?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to deactivate a production APK, upload a beta APK, save my changes, and publish.

Right now I am in a situation where I cannot get a beta test link because my app is not published. I'm fine with publishing, but I don't want my production app published with it. This is why I want to deactivate the production APK.

Google Play is not letting me save my changes. It says 'check the errors in the form' (there are no errors). I've found when I leave the production APK and only upload a new beta APK, then I can save changes (again - this is not what I want).

Am I missing something or is this impossible outside of uploading a dummy production APK or making an entirely new app?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you first publish the beta and then un-publish the production app.

Also try a different browser. Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: As far as I know publishing isn't on a per-apk basis, it's all or nothing. Can I specifically unpublish only the production apk?

Comment: This has no effect. It is published or not-published. Once you promote an app to production, you cannot remove it. Terrible.